# Strassen's algorithm recursive matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am trying to use Strassens algorithm to multiply two matrices recursively. I want to keep dividing the matrices into 4 parts until I end up with a matrix of 1x1 == base case of 1. I've worked it out by hand, and I've checked every 2x2 and 1x1 calculation on several calculators and my answers are right, but when I try to combine the 2x2 in the last part (the final r, s, t,u 2x2 matrices that will equal the new matrix) I dont seem to get the right answer. About 90% of my final matrix is wrong, but the individual 2x2 and 1x1 are correct.
This should be the answer, but instead I get something else.
[image][image][image]

Comment: Honestly, it's difficult (for me) to decipher your work. At any rate, does $r=ae+bg?$

Comment: The r = p5 + p4 - p2 + p6. So it would end up being the the top left corner of the matrix.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative!

Comment: Oh I see! So I have my a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h labeling wrong in some cases because I flipped the order of the 2x2 matrices which is causing me to compute the wrong thing.